# Пользователи переопределяют input hidden

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Доброе время суток, есть форма:

```
<form id="appointment-form" class="mt-3">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <button id="appointment-send" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " onclick="appointment_send()">
      <?php echo $button_submit; ?>
    </button>   
  </form>
```

и скрипт который отправляет форму для валидации на сервер:

```
 function appointment_send() {    
    $.ajax({
     url: 'index.php?route=appointment/item_appointment/add',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#appointment-form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                },
                }
  });
}
```

Все хорошо работает кроме того, что любой пользователь в форме может изменить значение скрытого инпута item_id и он отправиться на сервер в измененном виде, вопрос как исключить возможность редактирование скрытого поля пользователями сайта?

Comment: в любом случае надо проверять сообщения на валидность на стороне сервера

Comment: Никак. Клиентская часть приложения находится под полным контролем пользователя. Все данные, пришедшие от клиента должны проверяться сервером.

Comment: форма находится в попапе, попап открывается по клику на button  onclick с item_id  я его проверяю перед открытием попапа, а дальше ведь перед отправкой можно заменить item_id на любой другой существующий ...

Comment: В таком случае, єсли есть такая проблема сохраняйте значения выбранное пользовательому ещё в сессию, сравнивайте на бекенде при сохранении и тд. и очищайте значения в сессии. Или ещё вариант хэшировать значения в input, а на бекенде проверять какому именно значению принадлежит хеш, пользователю будет сложнее подменить хеш, но работать будет только с небольшим количеством возможных значений для input, а то проверка долго работать будет.